# Renaming group layer using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, group-layer

How do I rename a group layer in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy?

In ArcMap I can do so thus:

```
groupLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"Path to grouplayer.lyr")# empty group layer as template
groupLayer.name = some string
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataframe, groupLayer, add_position='TOP')
```

I can't find an analogous way to do this in ArcGIS Pro:

```
glyr = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(r"Path to GroupLayer.lyrx")# empty group layer as template
glyr.name = some string
theMap.addLayer(glyr, add_position='TOP')
```

While the above code adds the group layer, it does not rename it, and it does not flag an error so I'm not really sure what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `glyr` variable is a [`LayerFile`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layerfile-class.htm) object, not a [`Layer`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm). It represents the *file* your group layer is stored in, not the group layer itself.  Note that a layer file can contain multiple layers, eg:

[image]

The `LayerFile` object doesn't have a `.name` property and doesn't raise an error when setting a non-existent property.  You could do this and nothing would happen:

```
glyr.foo= "bar"
glyr.name = "some string"
glyr.another_nonexistent_property = "nothing"
```

Your group layer is a `Layer` in the `LayerFile`, and you can access it using the `.listLayers()` method, e.g.

```
lyr_file = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(r"path to.lyrx")  # LayerFile object
group_layer = lyr_file.listLayers("Your template Group Layer name")[0]  # Layer object
group_layer.name = "An Updated Name"
```

Comment: thanks, I was stuck so this really helped!